# Creating an efficient recursive function to sort a List<template> class

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, merge, linked-list

this is my first question on Stack Overflow so please be gentle. Thank you in advance for any responses, you all seem to really know what you're doing when it comes to machinespeak.

I have been building a Linked List toolkit template and the last additions I need to make are a sort() function and a merge() function.

This is my private member variable of the node structure:

```
  struct node
        {
            Item data;              // the variable containing the data in the node.
            node* next;             // the pointer to the next node in the list.
            node( Item _data, node* _next = NULL )  // constructor to build a node when data or the link is already known
            {
                data = _data;       
                next = _next;
            }
        };
 node* head;
```

This is my simple sorted function to test if the list is sorted in ascending order:

```
template <class Item>
bool List<Item>::sorted( )
{
    node* cursor;       // allocate a node pointer for traversal

    for ( cursor = head; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->next)     // loop from head until NULL
        if ( cursor->data > cursor->next->data )
            return false;       // if we ever find that the data in a node is greater than the data in the next node, return false

    return true;        // if we reach this point, the list is in ascending order
}
```

I wrote this function as a means for a simple base case if I was able to solve the sort() function recursively, alas I havn't been able to achieve that goal. NOTE: I'd be equally happy with an iterative solution as I would be with a recursive one.

Now; the merge() function ( Please note that if I can get sort working the assertion will be replaced with two calls to sort() )!

```
template <class Item>
    List<Item> List<Item>::merge(List<Item>& list1, List<Item>& list2)
    {          // libraries used: <algorithm> for sort() and <cassert> for assert();

        if ( list1.head == NULL )   // if the first list is empty, just return the second list
            return list2;
        if ( list2.head == NULL )   // if the second list is empty, just return the first list
            return list1;

        assert ( sorted() && otherList.sorted() );    // if this assertion is false, the function will not work.

        List<Item> newList;

        node* cursor1 = head;
        node* cursor2 = otherList.head;

        while ( cursor1 != NULL && cursor2 != NULL )
        {
            if (cursor1 == NULL)
            {
                while (cursor2 != NULL)
                {
                    newList.headInsert(cursor2->data);
                    cursor2 = cursor2->next;
                }
            }
            if (cursor2 == NULL)
            {
                while (cursor1 != NULL)
                {
                    newList.headInsert(cursor1->data);
                    cursor1 = cursor1->next;
                }
            }
            if (cursor1->data < cursor2->data)
            {
                newList.headInsert(cursor1->data);
                cursor1 = cursor1->next;
            }
            if (cursor2->data < cursor1->data)
            {
                newList.headInsert(cursor2->data);
                cursor2 = cursor2->next;
            }
            else
                if (cursor1->data == cursor2->data)
                {
                    newList.headInsert(cursor1->data);
                    newList.headInsert(cursor2->data);
                    cursor1 = cursor1->next;
                    cursor2 = cursor2->next;
                }
        }

        clear();
        head = newList.head;
    }
```

The sort function is where I'm really lost. I've looked through alot of answered questions on this site but didn't find any that really had what I was looking for. If possible I was hoping to have a function that was declared like this

```
void List<Item>::sort( )
```

and if possible I'd be even more grateful if someone could explain to me how to implement my merge() function more like this

```
void List<Item>::merge(List<Item>& L2)
```

I think it would be awesome if I could implement merge as a function that rather than assigning the merged nodes to a new List, It could easily take a another List and essentially merge sort them onto my main list like so

```
myList.merge(otherList);
```

I do realize that there are many similar questions already answered on this site alone, so please don't just link me to another question because chances are I've seen it and came out empty-handed (for this question at least). The thing is, even after poring over the questions and responses I still havn't been able to find out the answer to MY problem. I don't want to mimic someone else's code unless I have good reason to. This is more of a learning exercise for me and I just have writer's block on the best way to do this. I'd be happy to upload any other chunks of my code, or add more commentary on my thought process, and criticism is more than welcome. Any formatting tips would be appreciated as well.

Regards,

A newbie coder with a passion

for rclgdr

```
 template <class Item>
    void List<Item>::sort( )
    {
        if ( head == NULL || head->next == NULL )   // the list is empty or contains only one node, so it doesn't require sorting
            return;

        node* cursor = head;        // the cursor will be used for traversal
        node* smallest = head;      // this will always point to the node with the lowest data value
        node* was_smallest = head;  // tthis will point to the smallest data if a smaller value is found by the cursor
        node* back = head;          // this is a previous pointer, pointing at the node behind the cursor
        node* temp;                 // I always declare a temporary cursor just in case, it will be returned to heap anyway

        while ( cursor != NULL )        //cursor has originated at the head, and will go until it reaches NULL
        {
            if ( cursor->data < smallest->data )        // compare the data to the current smallest data
            {
                was_smallest = back;        // if the smallest was trumped by the cursor's data, set was_smallest to smallest
                smallest = cursor;          // smallest is where the cursor is pointing
            }
        back = cursor;              // always point back at where the cursor is
        cursor = cursor->next;      // THEN move the cursor, back is pointing at the previous node
        }

        if ( head != smallest )     // if the head is not the smallest (it SHOULD be!)
        {
            was_smallest->next = head;      // link was_smallest to the new head, essentially making it the new head
            temp = head->next;              // first use of temp, point it after the head
            head->next = smallest->next;    // after the head ( not TEMP! ) is linked from the new head (smallest)
            smallest->next = temp;          // link smallest to the head's link
        }

        //  I believe I need a recursive call here I think (head != smallest) is the base case?

    }


       template <class Item>
        void List<Item>::merge(List<Item>& otherList)
        {          // libraries used: <algorithm> for sort() and <cassert> for assert();

            if ( list1.head == NULL )   // if the first list is empty, just return the second list
                return list2;
            if ( list2.head == NULL )   // if the second list is empty, just return the first list
                return list1;

            assert ( sorted() && otherList.sorted() );    // if this assertion is false, the function will not work.

            List<Item> newList;

            node* cursor1 = head;
            node* cursor2 = otherList.head;

            while ( cursor1 != NULL && cursor2 != NULL )
            {
                if (cursor1 == NULL)
                {
                    while (cursor2 != NULL)
                    {
                        newList.headInsert(cursor2->data);
                        cursor2 = cursor2->next;
                    }
                }
                if (cursor2 == NULL)
                {
                    while (cursor1 != NULL)
                    {
                        newList.headInsert(cursor1->data);
                        cursor1 = cursor1->next;
                    }
                }
                if (cursor1->data < cursor2->data)
                {
                    newList.headInsert(cursor1->data);
                    cursor1 = cursor1->next;
                }
                if (cursor2->data < cursor1->data)
                {
                    newList.headInsert(cursor2->data);
                    cursor2 = cursor2->next;
                }
                else
                    if (cursor1->data == cursor2->data)
                    {
                        newList.headInsert(cursor1->data);
                        newList.headInsert(cursor2->data);
                        cursor1 = cursor1->next;
                        cursor2 = cursor2->next;
                    }
            }
            clear()
            head = newList.head;
        }
```

Comment: It so happens that I've just looked at sort algorithms in wikipedia, and merge sort is described there, too, and all others.

Comment: Even C-like code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: @laune Indeed, but wikipedia's page doesn't appear to be in c. Also, I'm not looking for standard type of merge sort. I'm looking to find a way to sort my linked list using only a back pointer and a next pointer, recursively if possible. This is where I am so far

Comment: The code is too long, what I did was essentially allocated multiple pointers, initialized most to head. And then used a pointer to keep track of the smallest value, the previous smallest value, the cursor, and then cursor->back and next. I would traverse the list with the cursor and if I found a data smaller than the head, I swapped the head and that node. But, it doesn't work.

Comment: You could declare a `dummy` node on the stack when merging. Just append everything to that and then return `dummy.next`. This will save your effort on edge case checking. Also, there is a bug in your `sorted()` method. It leads to segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2912836 Would you mind explaning what a dummy node is? Sorry, I'm brimming with questions and have no one to answer them in my day-to-day life. And edge case checking? Finally, Would the bug in sorted be that when cursor is at the end, I compare the data to NULL? Thank You once again for taking the time out of your day to help me. I'm extremely grateful.

Comment: @rUaCirculurQueue_iWannaInsert Dummy node is just a technique could be used with linked list. You declare a node whose only purpose is to be a head so that you can always append to it without checking your cursor. The bug in your `sorted()` happens when the `cursor` points to the last node. The `cursor` is not `NULL` yet but `cursor->next` is already `NULL`. So `cursor->next->data` will get you a segmentation fault.

Comment: The merge function should be appending to the end of a list, not inserting into the head of a list. There should just be one compare done if(cursor1->data <= cursor2->data), with an else. Append cursor1 node if it's <=, else append cursor2 node.

Comment: It looks like your sort function is trying to do something similar to a bubble sort, which is relatively slow, and would not be using the merge function you wrote. I added a code example to my answer that uses an array of head pointers to nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively splitting a list into sub-lists for sorting is inefficient. HP / Microsoft STL std::list::sort uses an array of n pointers to nodes, where array[i] is a list of size 2^i (except array[n-1] can be larger), plus a temp pointer to a node. The nodes are "merged" into the array one at a time. One all nodes are merged, the array is then merged to create a sorted list.

You could also implement a more conventional bottom up sort using 4 pointers to nodes (2 "source", 2 "destination" poitners) and a count for sub-list size (1,2,4,8, ..., until >= size of list)

Ancient example C code. The array is static, but if this code is converted into a class, then the array would be a class member. Note the comment about NODE.next and LIST.first which was used to simplify appending to an empty list. Some STL code uses a similar method, but you could just add the code to check for empty list handling without the assumptions about next and first being the first members of a structure (which means they have the same address as the structure).

```
#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* number of lists */

typedef unsigned long long UI64;

/*      MergeLists() casts an instance of LIST to NODE      */
/*      and uses NODE.next as the equivalent of LIST.first  */

typedef struct _NODE{
struct _NODE * next;        /* must be first member of NODE */
UI64 data;
}NODE, *PNODE;

typedef struct _LIST{
NODE *first;                /* must be first member of LIST */
}LIST, *PLIST;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      data                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static LIST aList[NUMLISTS];    /* array of lists */

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      SortList                                                        */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void SortList(LIST *pList)
{
NODE * pNode;
LIST mList;                             /* merged list */
int i;

    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for null ptr */
        return;

    /* merge nodes into aList[] */
    while(NULL != (pNode = GetFirstNode(pList))){
        MergeNode(pNode);
    }

    /* find 1st non empty aList[] */
    for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i].first == NULL); i++);
    if(i >= NUMLISTS){                  /* if all empty */
        pList->first = NULL;            /*   return null list */
        return;
    }

    pList->first = aList[i].first;      /* plist = aList[i] */
    aList[i].first = NULL;              /* clear aList[i] (optional) */

    for(i++; i < NUMLISTS; i++){        /* merge remaining aList[] */
        if(aList[i].first != NULL){
            MergeLists(&mList, &aList[i], pList);
            pList->first = mList.first;
        }
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      MergeNode   merge a node into the array of lists                */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void MergeNode(NODE *pNode)
{
LIST sList;                             /* source list */
LIST mList;                             /* merged list */
int i;

    if(pNode == NULL)                   /* return if null ptr */
        return;

    sList.first = pNode;                /* src list = node */

    /* merge into array */
    for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i].first != NULL); i++){
        MergeLists(&mList, &aList[i], &sList);
        sList.first = mList.first;
    }
    if(i == NUMLISTS)                   /* update array */
        i--;
    aList[i].first = sList.first;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      MergeLists  dst = merge(src1, src2)                             */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void MergeLists(LIST *plDst, LIST *plSrc1, LIST *plSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst, *pSrc1, *pSrc2;             /* node ptrs */

    pDst = (NODE *)plDst;               /* treat list same as node */
    pSrc1 = GetFirstNode(plSrc1);       /* init ptrs to nodes */
    pSrc2 = GetFirstNode(plSrc2);

    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            pDst->next = pSrc2;
            pDst = pDst->next;
            /* if end of src2, dst = rest of src1 */
            if(NULL == (pSrc2 = GetFirstNode(plSrc2))){
                pSrc1->next = plSrc1->first;
                pDst->next = pSrc1;
                plSrc1->first = NULL;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            pDst->next = pSrc1;
            pDst = pDst->next;
            /* if end of src1, dst = rest of src2 */
            if(NULL == (pSrc1 = GetFirstNode(plSrc1))){
                pSrc2->next = plSrc2->first;
                pDst->next = pSrc2;
                plSrc2->first = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      GetFirstNode                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
NODE * GetFirstNode(LIST * pSrc)
{
NODE * pNode;

    if(pSrc == NULL)                        /* return if null ptr */
        return NULL;
    pNode = pSrc->first;                    /* get node */
    if(pNode != NULL){
        pSrc->first = pNode->next;          /* advance list ptr */
        pNode->next = NULL;                 /* reset node ptr */
    }
    return pNode;
}
```

Comment: Ok good to know! As for the first method, I'm sorry but I just don't see where the sorting takes place. I know this is dissimilar but could this work for my sort()? Could I fill a regular array[list.length] with all of the data in each node, sort the array using std::sort and then replace the data in each node as I increment through the array? That feels like cheating and is surely inefficient though.

Comment: You use std::list to create and work with the list and std::list::sort which uses an efficient sort (Visual Studio uses the array method).

Comment: Since I have built my own list class am I able to use std::list::sort? I started from scratch and did not #include <list>. But, If I can then; in all reality you have just answered my question and made my life much easier. I do write in vS. but I guess what I'm saying is with my own template class of List<Item> that is built upon node structures what would the code look like if I am able to use std::list::sort to easily sort? If that is possible I can use that to finish my merge function and then continue on making my own sort member when I finish my study on sorting methods.

Comment: If it's your own list class, then you need to create your own sort program. You can look at <list> in under ...visual...VC\include\... . I could also post an example program, but I don't know if this is homework, in which case you're supposed to show an attempt. I can explain the algorithm in more detail.

Comment: Our homework for linked lists was due ~month ago and only involved a merge method and inserting and removing. I really want to not just pass but actually understand the code so I've been tweaking the project ever since. Originally it started out as us just connecting node*s to one another, we havn't even reached templates yet. I would love an example but If possible can I post my most recent attempt first? I don't think it fits in a comment though, so how can I show it to you?

Comment: so essentially while I do take a compsci class, this is more the fact that I enjoy playing around with and improving my code as I learn more in the c# language. Basically every container class we had to implement I have converted to dynamic memory and templates just for the lolz.

Comment: Hold on, I'll add my sort function to my original question

Comment: To show your attempt at code, you can answer your own question. First try to create a function that merges two already sorted lists and returns a pointer to the merged list. If the list is a double linked list (previous and next pointers), ignore the previous pointers for the sort / merge process as this can be done in a final step.

Comment: My reputation is too low to answer my own question before 8 hours after post. I did edit the code I have thus far(I've changed it many times) onto the original question. I know the sort function is far from complete but I think the merge is close. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to look at is what the high level description of your solution is. It looks like you want to do merge sort, and for that the steps are:

- split the input into two (roughly equivalent size) lists
- independently sort both
- merge the results together

You mention that you want to have `sort` be a member function so just make it:

```
void List::sort(); // ignoring template arguments here
```

For the implementation, you first need to split the list into two, without assuming that you know the correct size, you can split in half by creating a new list (local) and moving every other node from this node to the other list. At this point you have the two lists that you can recursively sort and then you would call `merge`

In the same way, you can implement `merge` as a member function that takes the other list:

```
void List::merge(List & other);
```

Note a couple of changes in the interface. The first is that if you want to do a in-place operation, there is no point on returning a *copy* of the list, you can return nothing (the caller already has the object) or you could return a reference to this list.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. What truly answered my question HOW i could split the list. I've heard of parsing but havn't learned it yet. The idea that I can simply add every other node into the dummy list is brilliant. But, after I break my list into two roughly equal sized lists, am I able to continually break these down until I have many lists with either one or two nodes? I guess what I'm trying to ask is can I have a recursive call that breaks once each list is at most 2 nodes? As for returning the copy of the list. where did I do that? Thank You so much for your help btw!

Comment: So sorry for being a needy little girl but I have some more questions about your explanation if you are willing to answer them. Let's get this out of the way: I am very new to coding, but I enjoy doing it.     1.) You say to make sort() a member function, which is exactly what I want, but you also say to ignore the template arguments. Is it possible to declare functions in a template class and then implement them not as template functions? If so that could really improve all of my code in general. If you don't feel like explaining everything do you at least know of a good read on templates?

Comment: @rUaCirculurQueue_iWannaInsert: *ignoring the template* was just for exposition, so that the answer would not be littered with all the detail, but in real code you cannot ignore that it is a template. You can provide the definition of the member functions inside the class definition and there you can avoid naming the template arguments, but those are still templated, not free functions. Sorry if that comment caused confusion.

Comment: Rodriguez - dribeas. Wow, I really don't know how to tag people yet, hope you see this. But seriously, no apology necessary. It's people like you (118k Rep!) that help all of us computer engineers stay interested and thinking critically when our teachers just don't have the time or interest to answer our little questions here and there. I salute you and thank you for the effort you put into this website and helping make coding a hobby and not a burden. Praise be.

Comment: @rUaCirculurQueue_iWannaInsert: You tag by prepending an @ sign, and you can even <tab> to autocomplete the user. But you need not tag me (maybe you cannot even do it) here since being a comment on an answer of mine I get notified automatically. Piece of advice: don't trust the rep number, it is just a number. Take the answers understand them and value them by what they contain, not who wrote them. Not everyone with high rep is reliable, and not everyone with low rep is unreliable. Be critical with answers.

Comment: Truly, that advice should be applied everywhere in life. I was applauding your rep for the obvious effort you put into helping other programmers, but I was really thanking you for the answer. The way you suggested splitting a list in half is simple, intuitive, and a new method for me. It didn't completely answer my question, but any time someone helps me learn something new in coding I am thankful for it, and I am certain I will use that simple idea in the future.